# Accessing a private JSON File with API key / secret key failing

Tags: json, reactjs, api, shopify

Hope you are having a good day. I am trying to learn Shopify dev but I am really stuck. I have gone through the whole tutorial available but still do not understand how to perform a REST API Call with the API key info.

I want to be able to query a json file with GET, but cannot seem to connect without any error. I have posted in Reddit and the Shopify forum but have had no response. I feel like I am missing something really obvious. I have spent hours looking around the documentation and cannot get this to work.

I keep getting the error "`errors: '[API] Invalid API key or access token (unrecognized login or wrong password)`' " from the code to try to access that JSON. I have posted here as well but the info hasn't helped unfortunately.  The code I am using is below:

```
fetch('https://<API-KEY>:<API-SECRET-KEY>@test-store-cap.myshopify.com/admin/api/2020-07/checkouts.json')
   .then(response => response.json())
   .then((jsonData) => {
    // jsonData is parsed json object received from url
   var data = jsonData;
   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
      {
        var obj = data[i];
        console.log("Email: " + obj.email + ", Phone Number: " + obj.phone);
      }
   console.log(jsonData)
  }) 


.catch((error) => {
  // handle your errors here
  console.error(error)
 })
```

I honestly have no idea why it keeps giving me this error, despite explicitly using the api key in the URL (I have taken mine out). I have tried the url with and without the api keys in it. I haven't used the imported ones from .env yet as I am just trying to get this test working before I make it adaptable. I got this some of this code from stack overflow and I am completely out of ideas. I heard btoa was required but I used that with `npm install btoa` but could not import it and that did not work either.

I have been trying many ways to pass the info into the URL, many different questions on here keep returning me to the same issue. The error given is given due to the connection but it does not allow access so it does connect to the URL, but for the life of me I cannot find out why.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you should get an error of the following sort:

> Request cannot be constructed from a URL that includes credentials:

In order to make a valid request your fetch should look like this:

```
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(API_KEY+ ':' + API_PASSWORD));

fetch('https://test-store-cap/admin/api/2020-07/checkouts.json', {headers: headers})
   .then(response => response.json())
...
```

If `btoa` doesn't work for you there are many `base64` encoders for `npm` that you can use.

I hope that by `API-SECRET-KEY` you mean the `API Password` and not the `Shared Secret` since if you are using the Shared secret it's wrong.

---

That said what you are trying to do is **REALLY REALLY bad**. The admin API shouldn't be used on the front end, since you are exposing your credentials to everyone and if you haven't set your permissions only to read and limited them, you are opening a huge security hole.

There are two API's:

- Admin API (that's REST and GraphQL)
- Storefront API (which is GraphQL based)

That said the Storefront API is very limited but it's secure.

The Admin API should be used only in applications or any kind of a back-end language that will not expose your credentials to the public.

The Admin API can be used on the front-end in very specific cases and should be done from developers who fully understands the permissions and the Shopify platform and even then it's not a good idea.

---

If you are still learning, the Shopify REST API is not for the front-end, you should use the [Storefront API](https://shopify.dev/docs/storefront-api/getting-started) instead.

Comment: Thanks for replying, will try it. I had no idea about those security issues however I do not understand how it would be a problem if the store accessing the front end embedded app could see it's own credentials, what would be the problem there? Also from what I see the storefront API doesn't allow the access of abandoned carts - does that mean that I should be forced to use the Admin API?

Comment: If someone opens your app and see the XHR request the credentials will be there (that's the easy way). There is no way to hide credentials on the front end, so if you don't want something to bee seen don't use it on the front-end. Yes you can't access the abandon carts from the front-end, you should access it from the back-end pass it to the front-end.

Comment: thanks again @drip . Just to clarify, is an npm server handling requests the back end while the embedded app is the front end?

Comment: There is no `npm server` term, not sure what you mean here. Front end is consider every language that loads once the DOM is ready (html/css/javascript), back-end is considered languages that loads before the DOM (nodejs/php/python/ruby/etc...). So you need to use the Back-end language to handle the request (fetch) and pass the response to the front-end via custom end point that you can request from the front-end. If you don't understand this concept it's too early to jump on the app wagon as of yet.

Comment: ah, in the tutorial they need an npm server to be ran. Thanks for the help! I will try to do the calls using php and will see if I can present with php, if not I will use a front end language. I do understand I may be running before I can walk but I am eager to start this project :)